# Expanded View using Html Css For Given Design

Tags: html, css, reactjs

[image: Ux design is some like this]

Hi, I have UX design something like this given for 1200px resolution width. But when the html is loaded in browser, since the resolution of window is bigger, there is around 200px gap on right side. How to expand this divs (also all the content inside div) to fit full screen for different resolutions greater than 1200px? i tried using rem instead of px but it only helps only when resolution is below 1200px  not for expanding beyond 1200px

Comment: Try a percentage of vw, which would be the viewport width https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/Building_blocks/Values_and_units

Comment: are you using it as a background?

Comment: It is not used as background, each div has a set of drop down and some text inside it. this drop and text should also expand

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you need?
This uses `100vw` to use the full width of the viewport in the wrapper.
Then the width of the children is set as a percentage of the parent.
My numbers are just an example.

```css
div {
  display:inline-block;
  height: 50px;
}

#wrapper {
  width: 100vw;
}

#one {
  background-color: green;
  width: 16%
}
#two {
  background-color: blue;
  width: 16%
}

#three {
  background-color: yellow;
  width: 50%
}

#four {
  background-color: red;
  width: 16%
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="one"></div>
  <div id="two"></div>
  <div id="three"></div>
  <div id="four"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, this was exactly what i was looking for. Any suggestions on best practices would greatly help like using em/rem and expanding text and div's inside the div.